Загрузить фото на сайт через Python и получить результат
Есть сайт https://tineye.com/.
Мне необходимо с помощью Python загружать туда фотографии и получать результаты.
Как загрузить фото на сайт и какую библиотеку лучше всего использовать?
(Спарсить данные смогу сам, нужна помощь только с загрузкой фото)

https://services.tineye.com/developers/tineyeapi/what_is_tineyeapi

Мне нужно не официальное Api, оно платное. Мне необходимо бесплатно с помощью парсинга

Фото можно загрузить с помощью браузера?

Не проверял лимиты по запросам и на защиту от робота.
import json
import requests

URL = "https://tineye.com/api/v1/result_json/"

image_path = "image.webp"
files = dict(image=open(image_path, "rb"))
params = dict(sort="score", order="desc")

response = requests.post(URL, params=params, files=files)
print(f"Status Code: {response.status_code} ({response.reason})")

if response.status_code == 200:
    # для удобства - сохраняю ответ в json
    with open("data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(response.json(), f, ensure_ascii=True, indent=2)

Входное изображение: https://0x0.st/XPM6.webp
Ответ: https://0x0.st/XPMY.json

Для получения более подробной информации вы можете изучить формулируемый запрос, который отправляется при загрузке изображения через "Консоль разработчика".
